# Curl Php Jsessionid cannot get or set

Tags: php, curl, jsessionid

okay so I am trying to curl to a website using jsessionid this is new to me.
I have a curl php script shown below how can I get the correct jsession id cookies and set them correctly .

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com/i/sec/stats.do';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");   // Cookie management.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

I then get this output how can I get and set the jsessionid.

```
This document you requested has moved temporarily.

It's now at https://www.example.com/i/sec/stats.do;jsessionid=c7dnSdlXc18Zpmqj1Tv1Rxq5TZDwD7dCpt5dpbg7LXmp1gnZs9V9!212735760!1390241207640.
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are getting 301 or 302 redirect response from your curl request. Use this option to handle redirection.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

But, if the site doesn't return the 301, 302 redirection response, then parse the url from the response, and call another curl request.

Comment: this does not help sorry